# Inserting ComboBox into dynamic Table

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, dynamic

I am trying to create a ComboBox within a dynamic table, but Im not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
        table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
        currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[1];

        ComboBox cbox=new ComboBox();
        System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem cboxitem=new System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem();
        cboxitem.Content="stuff";
        cbox.Items.Add(cboxitem);

        currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(cbox)); //Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Documents.TableCell.TableCell(System.Windows.Documents.Block)' has some invalid arguments
        currentRow.Cells.Add(new NumericUpDown()));
```

Once the user inputs data, how do I add a new row with new ComboBoxes to the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error already states, there's no `TableCell` constructur directly accepting an `UIElement` as its parameter. You'll need to wrap it using a `BlockUIContainer`:

```
currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new BlockUIContainer(cbox)));
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got: Error- Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'

Comment: @Rilcon42 Well, you shouldn't use `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` in WPF. You must use `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox` instead.